# JavaScript is throwing HTML errors

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to work through some errors. I've researched sites and made a few changes but still having trouble. Any assistance is appreciated. 
The goal is to take selected items on a SharePoint list and click a button that will open an email with list data. 
The errors are below:

SCRIPT1002: SCRIPT1002:
HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace. 
HTML1409: Invalid attribute name character. Attribute names should not contain ("),('),(<), or (=).
HTML1422: Malformed start tag. A self closing slash should be followed by a U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (>).
HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace. Email.aspx (807,105)
HTML1409: Invalid attribute name character. Attribute names should not contain ("),('),(<), or (=).

```
  Here's the latest code...

<script type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src=".../jquery-1.12.4.js"</script>
<script src=".../jquery.min"</script>
<script src=".../sprestlib.bundle.js"</script>
<script src=".../vue.min.js"</script>   
<script src=".../jquery-3.5.1.js"</script>
function clickMethod() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    sprLib.list('DRLs').items({
    listCols: {
        iD:  {dataName:'ID'},
        drlId:    {dataName:'Title'},
        artifactIdCopy:   {dataName:'ArtifactID'},
        assessmentId:   {dataName:'AssessmentIDCopy'},
        dueDate:   {dataName:'TaskDueDate'},
        AOREmails: {dataName:'AOREmails'},
        startDate: {dataName:'Assessment_x0020_ID_x0020_LU_x00'},
        teamMemberEmails: {dataName:'TeamMemberEmails'},
        artifactLink:   {dataName: 'Artifact_x0020_Link'},
        drlItemLink:   {dataFunc:function(objItem){return '<a href="URL='+objItem.ID+'">View DRL</a>'}}
    },
    queryOrderby: 'Title';
    })
    .then(findSelectedItems(arrData, items);  
    .catch(function(errMsg){console.error(errMsg) }); 
}
function findSelectedItems(spData, selectedItems){
    var emailBody = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){
        var itemID = selectedItems[i].id;

        for(var j = 0; j < spData.length; j++){
            if (spData[i].iD == itemID){
                emailBody += "Title: " + spData[i].drlId + "\r\n";  
            }
        }
    }

    sendMail(emailBody);
}

function sendMail(bodyString) {

    var message = encodeURIComponent(bodyString);   
    //var yourMessage = document.getElementById('AORNames');  
    var subject = document.getElementById('DRLID').value;
    var emails = document.getElementById('AOREMails').value;
    var mail = "mailto:" + emails + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;
    window.location.href = mail;    
}
 </script>
<button @click="clickMethod()">Send Email</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend splitting out the javascript into separate files. Then you'd just need to do `<script src='/my-new-file.js'></script>` in the html file instead of mixing and trying to match like what's happening at the moment.

Alternatively if you want to keep it like you have it now, on the first line, removing the closing script tag and move all of the other script tags outside. Like this:

```
<body><button @click="clickMethod()">Send Email</button>
<script src=".../jquery-1.12.4.js"</script>
<script src=".../jquery.min"</script>
<script src=".../sprestlib.bundle.js"</script>
<script src=".../vue.min.js"</script>   
<script src=".../jquery-3.5.1.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clickMethod() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    sprLib.list('DRLs').items({
    listCols: {
        iD:  {dataName:'ID'},
        drlId:    {dataName:'Title'},
        artifactIdCopy:   {dataName:'ArtifactID'},
        assessmentId:   {dataName:'AssessmentIDCopy'},
        dueDate:   {dataName:'TaskDueDate'},
        AOREmails: {dataName:'AOREmails'},
        startDate: {dataName:'Assessment_x0020_ID_x0020_LU_x00'},
        teamMemberEmails: {dataName:'TeamMemberEmails'},
        artifactLink:   {dataName: 'Artifact_x0020_Link'},
        drlItemLink:   {dataFunc:function(objItem){return '<a href="URL='+objItem.ID+'">View DRL</a>'}}
    },
    queryOrderby: 'Title';
    })
    .then(findSelectedItems(arrData, items);  
    .catch(function(errMsg){console.error(errMsg) }); 
}
function findSelectedItems(spData, selectedItems){
    var emailBody = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){
        var itemID = selectedItems[i].id;

        for(var j = 0; j < spData.length; j++){
            if (spData[i].iD == itemID){
                emailBody += "Title: " + spData[i].drlId + "\r\n";  
            }
        }
    }

    sendMail(emailBody);
}

function sendMail(bodyString) {

    var message = encodeURIComponent(bodyString);   
    //var yourMessage = document.getElementById('AORNames');  
    var subject = document.getElementById('DRLID').value;
    var emails = document.getElementById('AOREMails').value;
    var mail = "mailto:" + emails + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;
    window.location.href = mail;    
}
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'll try splitting it up. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I split it up; but it's still throwing error. But I'll work it out.

Comment: feel free to share the code on github and error so I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Just before your `function clickMethod` you are missing a starting `<script>` tag. That's why it says malformed start tag. It's missing. Hope that helps.